# Access ESXi guest console without a Windows OS?

Tags: vmware, esxi

As far as I know, vSphere Client is only available to run on Windows. And VSphere Client is the only tool which provides guest consoles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recent versions of ESXi support web clients. AFAIK, web client offer more services than traditional Windows application, vSphere client.

Answer (score 0):

You can try ssh if your virtual host is Linux?

Comment: thank you, but access to the ESXi host (the hypervisor's console is accessible without trouble) is not the problem. The question is how to access a guest console. I'm still reading; but I think with version 5.5, you can access guest console via VNC if you jump thru some exotic configuration hoops. I'm still reading.

Answer (score 0):

There are couples options for you to access the host directly without using vSphere Client (which is only for Windows).

- On Linux or Mac, you can try Wine and install vSphere Client.
- Use vSphere Web Client - this is the best option for non-Windows administrator.
- Install VNC on the Guest OS and access it directly.
- Use some other third party software such as [IntelliAdmin Remote Control](http://www.intelliadmin.com/index.php/products/).
- If the Guest OS is a Windows environment, use **mstsc /admin** to remote desktop to the OS console.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sadly, vSphere is listed in the WINE db as a no-go. VNC on the guest works, of course, once the guest OS has finished booting correctly; but doesn't give you access to BIOS or a boot which has hung or when you're trying to do an install off an ISO. I'll try the Web Client. I hadn't realized that vmWare had restored that option in 5.5